# HTML Text Wrapping Behind Vertical Navigation

Tags: css, html, navigation

I'm in the process of building a small website for my Roleplay group, and was overjoyed to figure out how to create a vertical navigation bar, but I'm noticing that on every display, the text falls behind it.

Is there a way to set where text begins and navigation ends?

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #d9d9d9;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  display: inline-block;
}

li {
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #555;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: #000;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: "Arial"
}

.active {
  background-color: #990000;
  color: white;
}

li a:hover {
  background-color: #990000 color: white;
}

#titletext {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Arial";
  font-size: 52;
}

#welcome {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Arial"
}

#intro {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Arial"
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="HOME_PAGE.css">
  <title>FFXIV RP Database</title>
  <style>
    div.head {
      background-color: #000000;
      color: white;
      text-decoration: none;
      margin: 5px 0 5px 0;
      padding: 20px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <!--NAVIGATION BAR-->
  <div class="Navigation">
    <ul>
      <li id="first"><img src="xiv logo.png" width="200px"></li>
      <li><a href="1.html" class="active">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="2.html">Characters</a></li>
      <li><a href="3.html">Story</a></li>
      <li><a href="4.html">Stats</a></li>
      <li><a href=".html">Contact</a>
        <li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <!--HEADER-->
  <div class="Head">
    <h1 id="titletext">FFXIV RP Database</h1>
  </div>
  <!--BELOW HEAD CONTENT-->
  <div class="Welcome">
    <p>
      <h2 id="welcome">Welcome to Eorzea!</h2>
      <div style="text-align:center;">
        <img src="group.png" width="40%">
      </div>
      <div class="IntroParagraph" style="text-align:center;" id="Intro">
        <p><i>"Such a marvel proof not only that the gods exist, but that they love, and that profoundly."</i>
          <br/><b>Orrick Ballard (Explorer and Map-Maker)</b><br/>
          <br/>
          <b>Eorzea</b> is the setting of Final Fantasy XIV. It is a vast region of <b>Hydaelyn</b>, and consists of the continent <b>Aldenard</b>, as well as its outlying islands. The realm has known many unique civilizations throughout its long history,
          and harbors many starkly different ones to this day. In the North, mountains loom tall overhead, buried under feet of snow and constantly lashed at by icy winds. And to the South, a vast expanse of unforgiving desert harbors few willing to brave
          its scalding heat.</p>
        <p>Despite its unique geography and vastly different regions, Eorzea holds the hearts of many for its expansive currents of <b>aether</b>, the very stones of the land rich with veins of the power-infused crystals. </p>
        <!--WRITE-UP: "EORZEA"-->
        <div class="Welcome">
          <p>
            <h2 id="welcome">City-States of Eorzea</h2>
            <div style="text-align:left;">
              <img src="eorzea.jpg" width="40%">
              <p>Due to its size, the region of Eorzea has been divided into six major city-states, each with their own unique cultures and climates:</p>
              <ol type="I">
                <li><b>Limsa Lominsa</b> is seated across a multitude of islands across the Southern Coast of the island <b>Vylbrand</b>, each connected into a single city by bridge.</li>
                <li><b>Gridania</b> stands to the east of Aldenard, its forests lush and vibrant. Its dense woodlands know many agriculturists and crafters, all whom seek to refine their craft. The city-state greatly emphasizes the harmony of man and nature,
                  its resident <b>White Mages</b> keeping the peace between the forest’s <b>Elementals.</b></li>
                <li><b>Ul’dah</b> sits buried in the sands of southern Aldenard, popular for its more hedonistic pleasures; ranging from fierce Gladiator fights to its gambling halls. Claimed sovereign by the <b>Sultana</b>, its rule truly belongs to the
                  wealthiest among its residents; affluence holds the reigns of the city, allowing the rich and influential to determine the fate of the city’s citizens. </li>
                <li>
            </div>
          </p>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To start, I would suggest pinning through your code and making some adjustments tot he structure. There looks to be a lot of missing tags (which I tried to correct in the fiddle). One tip would be to add comments to your closing `div` tags so you can see where each section ends.

With that said, what you can do is apply a `margin-left: 200px;` to your `.Welcome` class in order to shift everything over from the left side of the page. Since `200px` is the width of your fixed `navigation`, you want to compensate that width. And since your `Welcome` class is wrapping your `body` content, you would add the margin to this class

https://fiddle.jshell.net/kez8aLam/

```css
.Welcome {
  margin-left: 200px;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #d9d9d9;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  display: inline-block;
}

li {
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #555;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: #000;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: "Arial"
}

.active {
  background-color: #990000;
  color: white;
}

li a:hover {
  background-color: #990000 color: white;
}

#titletext {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Arial";
  font-size: 52;
}

#welcome {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Arial";
}

#intro {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Arial"
}
```

```html
<div class="home-wrap">

  <div class="Navigation">
    <ul>
      <li id="first"><img src="xiv logo.png" width="200px"></li>
      <li><a href="1.html" class="active">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="2.html">Characters</a></li>
      <li><a href="3.html">Story</a></li>
      <li><a href="4.html">Stats</a></li>
      <li><a href=".html">Contact</a>
        <li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <!--HEADER-->
  <div class="Head">
    <h1 id="titletext">FFXIV RP Database</h1>
  </div>
  <!--BELOW HEAD CONTENT-->
  <div class="Welcome">
    <p>
      <h2 id="welcome">Welcome to Eorzea!</h2>
      <div style="text-align:center;">
        <img src="group.png" width="40%">
      </div>
      <div class="IntroParagraph" style="text-align:center;" id="Intro">
        <p><i>"Such a marvel proof not only that the gods exist, but that they love, and that profoundly."</i>
          <br/><b>Orrick Ballard (Explorer and Map-Maker)</b>
          <br/>
          <br/>
          <b>Eorzea</b> is the setting of Final Fantasy XIV. It is a vast region of <b>Hydaelyn</b>, and consists of the continent <b>Aldenard</b>, as well as its outlying islands. The realm has known many unique civilizations throughout its long history,
          and harbors many starkly different ones to this day. In the North, mountains loom tall overhead, buried under feet of snow and constantly lashed at by icy winds. And to the South, a vast expanse of unforgiving desert harbors few willing to brave
          its scalding heat.</p>
        <p>Despite its unique geography and vastly different regions, Eorzea holds the hearts of many for its expansive currents of <b>aether</b>, the very stones of the land rich with veins of the power-infused crystals. </p>
      </div>
      </div>
      </div>
      <!--WRITE-UP: "EORZEA"-->
      <div class="Welcome">
        <p>
          <h2 id="welcome">City-States of Eorzea</h2>
          <div style="text-align:left;">
            <img src="eorzea.jpg" width="40%">
            <p>Due to its size, the region of Eorzea has been divided into six major city-states, each with their own unique cultures and climates:</p>
            <ol type="I">
              <li><b>Limsa Lominsa</b> is seated across a multitude of islands across the Southern Coast of the island <b>Vylbrand</b>, each connected into a single city by bridge.</li>
              <li><b>Gridania</b> stands to the east of Aldenard, its forests lush and vibrant. Its dense woodlands know many agriculturists and crafters, all whom seek to refine their craft. The city-state greatly emphasizes the harmony of man and nature,its
                resident <b>White Mages</b> keeping the peace between the forest’s <b>Elementals.</b></li>
              <li><b>Ul’dah</b> sits buried in the sands of southern Aldenard, popular for its more hedonistic pleasures; ranging from fierce Gladiator fights to its gambling halls.
                <li>Claimed sovereign by the <b>Sultana</b>, its rule truly belongs to the wealthiest among its residents; affluence holds the reigns of the city, allowing the rich and influential to determine the fate of the city’s citizens. </li>
            </ol>        
        </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason of why "text falls behind navigation" is: the `ul` element's position is `fixed`, which makes it detached from document (moved to another layer and does not occupy any space in the page). Thus the text occupies all page space and part of them falls behind `ul`.

As you may need `fixed` `ul` for good reason, the below code only adds one css rule -- define left padding for text, which leaves space for `ul` element display:

```
.Head, .Welcome {
    padding-left: 200px;
}
```

```css
ul {
 list-style-type: none;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 width: 200px;
 background-color: #d9d9d9;
 height: 100%;
 position: fixed;
 display: inline-block;
}

li {
 text-align: center;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #555;
}
 

li a {
 display: block;
 color: #000;
 padding: 8px 16px;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-family: "Arial"
}

.active {
 background-color: #990000;
 color: white;
}

li a:hover {
 background-color: #990000
 color: white;
}

#titletext {
 text-align: center;
 font-family: "Arial";
 font-size: 52;
}

#welcome {
 text-align: center;
 font-family: "Arial"
}

#intro {
 text-align:center;
 font-family: "Arial" 
}

.Head, .Welcome {
    padding-left: 200px;
}
```

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="HOME_PAGE.css">
  <title>FFXIV RP Database</title>
  <style>
   div.head {
    background-color: #000000;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin: 5px 0 5px 0;
    padding: 20px;
   }
  </style>
 </head>

 <body>
<!--NAVIGATION BAR-->
  <div class="Navigation">
   <ul>
    <li id="first"><img src="xiv logo.png" width="200px"></li>
    <li><a href="1.html" class="active">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="2.html">Characters</a></li>
    <li><a href="3.html">Story</a></li>
    <li><a href="4.html">Stats</a></li>
    <li><a href=".html">Contact</a><li>
   </ul>
  </div>
<!--HEADER-->
  <div class="Head">
   <h1 id="titletext">FFXIV RP Database</h1>
  </div>
<!--BELOW HEAD CONTENT-->
  <div class="Welcome">
   <p>
    <h2 id="welcome">Welcome to Eorzea!</h2>
    <div style="text-align:center;">
     <img src="group.png" width="40%">
    </div>
    <div class="IntroParagraph" style="text-align:center;" id="Intro">
     <p><i>"Such a marvel proof not only that the gods exist, but that they love, and that profoundly."</i>
     <br/><b>Orrick Ballard (Explorer and Map-Maker)</b><br/>
     <br/>
     <b>Eorzea</b> is the setting of Final Fantasy XIV. It is a vast region of <b>Hydaelyn</b>, and consists of the continent <b>Aldenard</b>, as well as its
     outlying islands. The realm has known many unique civilizations throughout its long history, and harbors many starkly different ones
     to this day. In the North, mountains loom tall overhead, buried under feet of snow and constantly lashed at by icy winds. And to the
     South, a vast expanse of unforgiving desert harbors few willing to brave its scalding heat.</p>
     <p>Despite its unique geography and vastly different regions, Eorzea holds the hearts of many for its expansive currents of <b>aether</b>, the
     very stones of the land rich with veins of the power-infused crystals. </p>
<!--WRITE-UP: "EORZEA"-->
  <div class="Welcome">
    <p>
     <h2 id="welcome">City-States of Eorzea</h2>
     <div style="text-align:left;">
      <img src="eorzea.jpg" width="40%">
      <p>Due to its size, the region of Eorzea has been divided into six major city-states, each with their own unique cultures and climates:</p>
       <ol type="I">
        <li><b>Limsa Lominsa</b> is seated across a multitude of islands across the Southern Coast of the island <b>Vylbrand</b>, each connected into a single city by bridge.</li>
        <li><b>Gridania</b> stands to the east of Aldenard, its forests lush and vibrant. Its dense woodlands know many agriculturists and crafters, all whom seek to refine their craft.
        The city-state greatly emphasizes the harmony of man and nature, its resident <b>White Mages</b> keeping the peace between the forest’s <b>Elementals.</b></li>
        <li><b>Ul’dah</b> sits buried in the sands of southern Aldenard, popular for its more hedonistic pleasures; ranging from fierce Gladiator fights to its gambling halls.
        Claimed sovereign by the <b>Sultana</b>, its rule truly belongs to the wealthiest among its residents; affluence holds the reigns of the city, allowing the rich and influential
        to determine the fate of the city’s citizens. </li>
        <li>
    </div>
   </p>
 </body>
</html>
```